# When to use return in recursive function?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm learning the BST recursive construction and found that the `insert` method does not use `return` keyword when implementing recursion, but the `contains` method do use the `return` key word. Can anybody explain this to me? Many thanks!

```
  static class BST {
    public int value;
    public BST left;
    public BST right;

    public BST(int value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    public BST insert(int value) {
      // Write your code here.
      // Do not edit the return statement of this method.
            if (value < this.value) {
                if (left == null) {
                    BST newBST = new BST(value);
                    left = newBST;
                } else {
                    left.insert(value);
                }
            } else {
                if (right == null) {
                    BST newBST = new BST(value);
                    right = newBST;
                } else {
                    right.insert(value);
                }
            }
      return this;
    }

    public boolean contains(int value) {
      // Write your code here.
            if (value < this.value) {
                if (left == null) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return left.contains(value);
                }
            } else if (value > this.value) {
                if (right == null) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return right.contains(value);
                }
            } else{
                return true;
            }
    }
```

Comment: `insert` does use the keyword `return`.

Comment: there's a `return this;`

Comment: In this case, the `insert` method return the object modified. This is useful if you want to do something like: `a.insert(2).insert(4).insert(3);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "insert" function only has a return statement right at the end, because all it has to return is "this", rather than being dependent on outside factors and the execution of the function.

So, short version: You use "return" when you need to, and you do not use "return" when you do not need to.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially because insert is not implemented as a function but contains is, meaning that insert just has side effects, it changes the state of BST. Contains is inherently a function - it returns an answer for a given input.

The fact insert returns `this` at the end is not necessary, it could just as easily have a void return value.

A functional version would return a new BST that is like the original but with the element inserted, and that would require use of the returned value, there would be a bit more complexity there.
(I'm not advocating a functional version here!)